# How to recognise logged in user?

Tags: php

I just made the registration form for my website, however I have zero knowledge on how to remember the user is logged in through the session. I think I could simply store his IP on a Table on my database when authenticated and remove it when he logs out.

Is there anything wrong about this approach? If there is what should I do instead of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PHP than you can do this:

```
 $_SESSION['logged_in_user'] = $username;
 ...
  // When you want to display something that is only for logged in users you do this:
  if (!empty($_SESSION['logged_in_user']))
  {
    // Authenticated user
    ...
  }
  else
  {
   // Not authenticated user
   ...
  }
```

And when he logs out you remove the username from the session

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in_user']))
{
  session_unset($_SESSION['logged_in_user']);
}
```

Comment: You can simplify this code by writing `if (!empty($_SESSION['logged_in_user'])` which will both check that the variable is set and that its value is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you do something like

```
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1;
```

when the user logs in, and check

```
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) { ...
```

on subsequent requests to see if the user on the page is logged in or not.

No databases required. You can put whatever details you'll need while the user is logged in into the session, like the user's username or other identifier.

One problem with your approach is that most people don't explicitly log out of websites, they just close the tab/window, and you don't know when that happens. Another is that IP addresses do not uniquely identify users.

Answer (score 1):

Well yes..
The IP your user has could change while he is on your site, or could actually be for multiple computers (that use a NAT).  Basically any network can have multiple computers using the same IP, and if one person on one computer logs in, another computer on the same network is also logged in.

The normal way is to store his user information in a session.  This session marks only his computer (because the session id is stored in a cookie).

Also, to cut down on queries to the database, I usually just load his username, id, etc into the session when he logs in, then just clear the session when he logs out.

Answer (score -1):

in your login, you can set a session variable:

```
$_SESSION['is_logged_in'] = true;
```

and then check it on pages that require login:

```
<?php
  if (!isset($_SESSION['is_logged_in']))
  {
    // redirect to login page
  }
?>
```

That is a really really simple way, but will get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Couple problems with this... you don't check if the key exists before using it (PHP notice), you negate it when it may not exist, and you compare it to `true` while negating it causes the opposite logic to what your comment implies.